# How to reference the recordset in a form without using Openrecordset()?

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

Is there a way to reference the recordset of a form without using Openrecordset()? My form has different records depending on different conditions, so it gets a little messy to do it that way. Is there anything similar to Me.Form.Recordset (which doesn't work, btw) that I can use? Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with the recordset?  If you only want to look at something in it, try `Me.RecordsetClone`.

Comment: You can also consider an unbound form.

Comment: HansUp: I need to loop through all records in the recordset to search for duplicate combo box assignments. The form should also be editable so I'm not sure if RecordsetClone would work since I think it is read only.
PeterT: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if RecordsetClone would work since I think it is read
>   only.

This is the type of comments I never learn to understand. Why don't you just try? It will take you less time than sitting wondering.

So follow Hans. The recordset will be updatable at the same level as the form.